# Operation over two arrays with different numblocks

Tags: dask

I am trying to implement [take_along_axis](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8708) for dask array.

What is the standard way to map an operation that takes in a block from dask array `A`, and the corresponding block from dask array `B`?

Should I use a rechunk when `A.numblocks != B.numblocks`?

Comment: I guess i will use rechunk anyway. The alternative would be to take multiple blocks from A, 1 block from B, and process them together, if `A.numblocks != B.numblocks`. But that is just too complex to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rechunking is fine.  Dask.array algorithms align chunks internally fairly frequently.  You might also consider using functions like `map_blocks` or `atop` if they work for you.  Dask developers optimize these.

- http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.atop
- http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks

These are only important though if you're constructing your own algorithms.  Normal use of dask.arrays does not really require thinking about rechunking explicitly.